# blender 2.8: where is the "axes" tool for moving vertices visually?

Tags: interface, edit-mode, 3d-manipulator

I started using blender 2.8 and I'm not being able to move a vertex on one direction like in Blender 2.7, since I can't find the little visual widget with axes (see below):

[image]

<sup>↑ *the widget in Blender 2.79*</sup>

Is there any way I can make this tool show, or at least a way that would let me select additional vertices in "move mode" (<kbd>G</kbd>) instead of needing to go in and out from the move mode for every vertex?

Comment: @othmanA what exactly is not working? select + press G + press X, or Y or Z should still work in 2.8. Are you trying a different approach? The question is not necessarily off topic (some features are changing for good with the new versions, and it's not clear whether this question is about a bug or a feature change), but it must be written more properly for us to understand: 1. what you're trying to do, 2. how, 3. what's wrong.

Comment: I hope they will keep the XYZ axis manipulator by default, like in 2.7, because it's very convenient

Comment: I can't confirm this as well, just tested an out-of-the-box blender 2.8 build, going into edit mode, G + X/Y/Z > works like expected.

Comment: @NicolaSap @ Ignatiamus you use to do it in 2.7 without having to press g+z/x/y because you have the axis, i know you can use 'move mode' but then you cant select other vertex nor add to your selection without having to deselect and select again this inconvenient if you are working on complex object .

Comment: Oh, you're talking about the 3D manipulator widget! I see now! Good news: it is present in 2.8. I'll post an answer in a second

Answer (score 10):

The 3D manipulator widget can be enabled from the toolshelf (left of the 3D viewport) using this "arrows" button:

> [image]

[image]

In addition to the "move along X,Y,Z" action, this manipulator also enables the "move on the XY, XZ or YZ plane" (see the little squares between the axes).

There are also other kinds of manipulators in the tool shelf that you can choose from: move, rotate, scale and all the three things combined.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using the Move tool, make sure Transform Pivot Point is set to Bounding Box Center (or whatever makes sense for your situation).

The below image shows it initially set to 3D Cursor in which case it doesn't move to the active selection. Then I changed it to Bounding Box Center which is more visually intuitive. This will position it at any selected vertex, the midpoint of a selected edge or the center of a selected face. It will position at the center of multiple selection as well.

One drawback is that the widget might get in the way if you are trying to select something behind it. But there are other ways around that too.

[image]